# Translating module options using apos.i18n?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I need an example of using the apostrophe-i18n module inside a custom widgets modules index.js file.

After searching through all of Apostrophes built-in modules, I realized that Apostrophe never uses i18n to translate javascript strings.

I tried the following (found in one module), but it says "self is not defined". How could I import the apostrophe-i18n module to translate my strings in index.js file?

```
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
    label: self.apos.i18n.__('Link Page'),
    addFields: {
        name: '_page',
        type: 'joinByOne',
        withType: 'apostrophe-page',
        label: self.apos.i18n.__('Page'),
        required: true,
        idField: 'pageId',
        filters: {
            projection: {
                title: 1,
                slug: 1
            }
        }
    }
};
```

---

**Edit for reference:**

i18n for module options is not required, since Apostrophe handles the locales for admin strings itself. After adding the widget to an `apos.area` or `apos.singleton` call, all strings appear inside `locale/en.json`, ready for translation (according to my observation).

It seems that `apostrophe-i18n` uses the browser language to determine the locale to use. This language has to be configured like this in `app.js`:

```
'apostrophe-i18n': {
  locales: ['en', 'de']
},
```

After that, all my translated strings inside `locale/de.json` were printed to the page.

---

The working code to use `self` inside modules (again, not needed for i18n):

```
module.exports = {

    construct: function(self, options) {
        options.label = self.apos.i18n.__('Link Page');
    },

    extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
    addFields: [
        {
            name: '_page',
            type: 'joinByOne',
            withType: 'apostrophe-page',
            label: 'Page',
            required: true,
            idField: 'pageId',
            filters: {
                projection: {
                    title: 1,
                    slug: 1
                }
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` doesn't exist outside the module's `construct` functions. Try instead

```
  construct: function(self, options) {
    options.label = self.apos.i18n.__('Link Page');
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped. But now I see that this isn't needed. Apostrophe handles i18n for admin menu itself. Nice!

I will update the question for reference.